# org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection - SubQuery error

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I try similar questions but without success. Please, Can someone help me on the question. I have the following POJOs:

```
@Entity
public class EntityA implements Serializable  {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
private int id;

@Column(length=9)
private String someField;

@Column(length=50)
private String anotherField;

Getters and Setters ......




    @Entity
    public class EntityB {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
private int id;


@OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL} )
private List<EntityA> listOfEntityA;


Getters and Setters ......
```

And I try to retrieve a list of objects of EntityA that are not present in the field list contained in EntityB

```
return (List<EntityA>) genericDAO.retrieveList("from EntityA e1 where e1.id not in ( select e2.listOfEntityA.id from EntityB e2 where e2.id =?1)" , myParamId );
```

and caught the exception

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection
```

Already tried also without subquery, passing as parameter the list of objects EntityA contained in the field of entityB, but again without success.

Can anyone tell me where I am wrong

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
String query =
    "SELECT entityA " +
    "FROM EntityA entityA " +
    "WHERE entityA.id NOT IN (" +
    "   SELECT entityAOfB.id " +
    "   FROM EntityB entityB " +
    "   JOIN entityB.listOfEntityA entityAOfB " +
    "   WHERE entityB.id = ?1";
    ")";
```

Comment: Thank you Nicolae Albu. It worked just right. I do not have much knowledge in this JOIN clause. I'll look for more information. Again, thank you very much.